Crashlytics 3.0.1 failed to apply plugin
After upgrading Crashlytics to 3.0.1 I'm receiving error
Failed to apply plugin 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics
It is too late to add actions as the callbacks already executed.
Did you try to call beforeVariants or onVariants from the old variant API
'applicationVariants' for instance ? you should always call beforeVariants or
onVariants directly from the androidComponents DSL block.

For version 2.9.9 and earlier it is working fine.
Only places where I'm using applicationVariants
        applicationVariants.all {
        addJavaSourceFoldersToModel(
            File(layout.buildDirectory.get().asFile, "generated/ksp/$name/kotlin")
        )
    }

    androidComponents {
    onVariants { variant ->
        var apkName = "Terminal-"
        apkName += android.defaultConfig.versionName + "-"
        apkName += variant.name
        apkName += ".apk"

        variant.buildConfigFields.put(Constants.EnableAnalyticsKey, buildConfigBoolean(true))
        variant.buildConfigFields.put(Constants.EnableCrashlyticsKey, buildConfigBoolean(true))

        variant.outputs.forEach { output ->
            if (output is com.android.build.api.variant.impl.VariantOutputImpl) {
                output.outputFileName.set(apkName)
            }
        }
    }
}

For Crashlytics plugin itself it is applied onEvalute
    afterEvaluate {
    val taskString = gradle.startParameter.taskRequests.toString()
    if (taskString.contains("EnvTest") || taskString.contains("Prod") || taskString.contains("Dev")) {
        apply(plugin = "com.google.gms.google-services")
        apply(plugin = "com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    }
}

due to project multiple build variants.
Is this bug of this version or I'm just using some depracated solution?
